# Javascript add new select index with data from database

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a selection that triggers another selection to select data from the database when the first selection is selected.

```html
<select id="brandSelect">
        <option value="10">Pilih Brand</option>
        <option value="20">AMD</option>
        <option value="30">Intel</option>
</select>
```

How to take the data from the database if option 1, 2, or 3 is selected, and the second selection option has a value in it? And if the user changes the option, the second selection index is reset.

Comment: so when user select any item from one dropdown, you want to select automatic value from second dropdown and want to fetch data from database ?

Comment: Can you use jquery?? Also you want on change of this selection you post to change another selection?

Comment: If the user select the option in the first dropdown, the second selection will fetch data from the database, and if the option in the first dropdown is change, the second selection option will change to. @Vishalmodi

Comment: What kind of jquery I have to use? @GeorgeStavrou

Comment: you can check answers from below, if it is not matched with your requirement let me know.

Comment: @DeanTristaNato i just put an answer. You need jquery to hear the "on" , or 'change' events. Bellow is an example. When you change the selection in the first. You change the selection to the 2on also. You might need another event handler. But that's what i understood from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code with Javascript Vanilla:

```
<body>
  <select id="brandSelect" onchange="optionSelected(this.value)">
    <option value="10">Pilih Brand</option>
    <option value="20">AMD</option>
    <option value="30">Intel</option>
  </select>
</body>

<script>
  function optionSelected(value) {
    alert(value)
    // DO Database Fetch Code Here
  }
</script>
```

And I will tell you there is a [good website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), we might not need jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

In the bellow Code, by changing the #brandselect you can triger change on the other select. I put specific value. You can add the value you want there.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#brandSelect', function() {
 // Here you change the selection of the other Select
  $('#graphs').val("20");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brandSelect">
  <option value="10">Pilih Brand</option>
  <option value="20">AMD</option>
  <option value="30">Intel</option>
</select>



<select id="graphs">
  <option value="10">AMD</option>
  <option value="20">NVidia</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('change', '#brandSelect', function() {
 // Here you change the selection of the other Select
  $('#brandSelect2').val("2");
  $('#brandSelect2').trigger("change");
  
})

$(document).on('change', '#brandSelect2', function() {
 // Here you change the selection of the other Select
  alert();
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brandSelect">
  <option value="10">Pilih Brand</option>
  <option value="20">AMD</option>
  <option value="30">Intel</option>
</select>

<select id="brandSelect2">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
```

first you need to handle change event and from based on that you can handle second dropdown change event.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brandSelect">
  <option value="10">Pilih Brand</option>
  <option value="20">AMD</option>
  <option value="30">Intel</option>
</select>

<select id="brandSelect2">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#brandSelect', function() {

  $('#brandSelect2').val("2");
  $('#brandSelect2').trigger("change");

})

$(document).on('change', '#brandSelect2', function() {

//here you can use ajax call to fetch data from database.
  alert();
})
</script>
```